# pandas max value in row & return df with value and column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    a    b    c    d    e
    1   .90  .95  .83  .56
   .95  .96  .87  .83  .63
   .83  .87  .83  .95  .81
```

How do I find the max value per row and the column it came from, so that it looks like:

```
a   1
b  .96
d  .95
```

Comment: read about `DataFrame.max` and `DataFrame.idxmax`

Comment: `pd.concat([df.idxmax(1),df.max(1)],1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) and [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
s=pd.Series(df.columns[np.argmax(df.values,axis=1)])
final=pd.DataFrame(df.lookup(s.index,s),s)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
result = df.max(axis=1)
result.index = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: You just answered a few minutes before me while I was verifying my program :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `idxmax()` function:

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'a':[100,95,83],'b':[90,96,87],'c':[95,87,83],'d':[83,83,95],'e':[56,63,81]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
```

Dataframe looks like this:

```
     a   b   c   d   e
0  100  90  95  83  56
1   95  96  87  83  63
2   83  87  83  95  81
```

Using the function idxmax we get which column does the max value per row belong:

```
print(df.idxmax(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0    a
1    b
2    d
```

Concatenating it with the original dataframe, to the get the corresponing value, given the column it belongs to.

```
df_result = pd.concat([df.idxmax(axis=1),df.max(axis=1)],axis=1)
print(df_result)
```

Output:

```
   0    1
0  a  100
1  b   96
2  d   95
```

Answer (score 1):

```
maxRow = df.idxmax(1)
maxValue = df.max(1)
print(pd.concat([maxRow , maxValue],1))
```

The `maxRow` variable gives the id of the maximum valued row in the dataframe,the 1 to to set the axis to row instead of column, Similarly, the `maxValue` gets the maxValues of the rows
`pd.concat` is to zip these two lists into a dataframe

Comment: Cheers, still new to answering